# Block a URL and its sub URL using Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL `http://example.com/web/en/press-release/`.
How can I block all users access and viewing that page and `http://localhost:10004/web/en/press-release/*` using `.htaccess`?

I want them only accessible from specific IPs.

I did like this but not working.

```
# Press Release Blocked Now
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} web/en/press-release/ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Your configuration looks like if you have modified a [hotlinking prevention](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images) example, but it has nothing to do with the [access control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) you should be using.

Comment: What's the connection between `example.com` and `localhost:10004`?

Answer (score 2):

If you [must](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when) use [`.htaccess` files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) you should know their limitations:

> `.htaccess` files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way
> to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file,
> containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a
> particular document directory, and the directives apply to that
> directory, and all subdirectories thereof.

This means you control the settings on *filesystem containers* rather than *webspace containers*, and the configuration by default applies to all subdirectories. Therefore, to achieve your goal you must place the `.htaccess` file to the file system path corresponding with the URL path `/web/en/press-release/`.

If the `/web/en/press-release/` on both `localhost:10004` and `example.com` refers to the same directory and both are served directly from the filesystem using Apache (i.e. it is not a [*reverse proxy*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)), the filesystem context is a good choice. From [Configuration Sections: What to use When](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#whichwhen):

> Choosing between filesystem containers and webspace containers is
> actually quite easy. When applying directives to objects that reside
> in the filesystem always use `<Directory>` or `<Files>`. When applying
> directives to objects that do not reside in the filesystem (such as a
> webpage generated from a database), use `<Location>`.
>
> It is important to never use `<Location>` when trying to restrict access
> to objects in the filesystem. This is because many different webspace
> locations (URLs) could map to the same filesystem location, allowing
> your restrictions to be circumvented.

Instead of [using mod_rewrite to control access](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html), Apache has direct [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) directives. Using them is more straightforward and makes your configuration easier to read and manage. The [`Require` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) from [mod_authz_core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html) has `ip`:

```
Require ip 192.0.2.100
Require ip 198.51.100.0/24
Require ip 2001:DB8:C0F:FEE::/64
```